# Convert string to channel ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I have a command for manually setting secret channel ID:

```
@client.command(aliases=['secret', 'setSecretChannel'])
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def set_secret_channel(ctx, id):
    global secret_channel_id
    secret_channel_id = id
    await ctx.send("ID set")
```

Another command uses secret_channel_id to move user to secret channel:

```
@client.command()
@commands.has_role('VIP')
async def joinSecret(ctx, password):
    author = ctx.message.author
    if password == joinSecret_password:
        await author.move_to(secret_channel_id)
        await ctx.send("Password correct")
    else:
        await ctx.send("Password incorrect")
    # delete author's message
```

However, following error occurs:

```
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Is there a way to convert string to channel ID?

**EDIT**

```
await author.move_to(int(secret_channel_id))
```

Converting to int doesn't seem to work too, now the error is:

```
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: await author.move_to(secret_channel_id) line

Comment: The ID must be of type `int`, so you can try `int(secret_channel_id)`

Comment: AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'. Still not working

Comment: Please updated your question to show what you are trying

Comment: You need get the `channel` object. You can use `client.get_channel(secret_channel_id)`

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out and now it works. I had to change

```
await author.move_to(secret_channel_id)
```

to

```
await author.move_to(client.get_channel(int(secret_channel_id)))
```